# Why I can not run custom image with QEMU?

Tags: linux, image, yocto, qemu

I have problem with running custom image through out QEMU. I created image test-img for machine qemuarm. It is derived from core-image-minimal. The compilation and the bitbake process for creating was without errors, I got the image files. Problem is that I can not run the img with runqemu command.

I tried: runqemu qemuarm test-img

```
runqemu - ERROR - Can't handle two unknown args: qemuarm test-img
Try 'runqemu help' on how to use it
runqemu - INFO - Cleaning up
```

runqemu test-img

```
runqemu - INFO - Running MACHINE=test-img bitbake -e ...
runqemu - ERROR - /home/traskos/yocto_live/build/tmp/deploy/images/test-img not a directory valid DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE
ls: cannot access '/home/traskos/yocto_live/build/tmp/deploy/images/test-img/*.qemuboot.conf': No such file or directory
runqemu - ERROR - Command 'ls -t /home/traskos/yocto_live/build/tmp/deploy/images/test-img/*.qemuboot.conf' returned non-zero exit status 2
runqemu - INFO - Cleaning up
```

What I do not understand, is why this commands are not working.
When I run command:
**runqemu qemuarm core-image-minimal**
or:
**runqemu core-image-minimal**
it will run succesfully.

This is the test-img.bb file:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Recipe created by bitbake-layers"
LICENSE = "Traskos"

require recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb

IMAGE_INSTALL += "custom-recipe"
IMAGE_FEATURES = "dev-pkgs"
```

inside /home/traskos/yocto_live/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemuarm

```
total 175380
-rw-r--r-- 2 traskos traskos   5843624 čec 27 12:15 zImage--5.4.205+gitAUTOINC+aaaf9f090d_943e7e1f32-r0-qemuarm-20220727082925.bin
lrwxrwxrwx 2 traskos traskos        78 čec 27 12:15 zImage-qemuarm.bin -> zImage--5.4.205+gitAUTOINC+aaaf9f090d_943e7e1f32-r0-qemuarm-20220727082925.bin
lrwxrwxrwx 2 traskos traskos        78 čec 27 12:15 zImage -> zImage--5.4.205+gitAUTOINC+aaaf9f090d_943e7e1f32-r0-qemuarm-20220727082925.bin
lrwxrwxrwx 2 traskos traskos        79 čec 27 12:15 modules-qemuarm.tgz -> modules--5.4.205+gitAUTOINC+aaaf9f090d_943e7e1f32-r0-qemuarm-20220727082925.tgz
-rw-rw-r-- 2 traskos traskos   1823111 čec 27 12:15 modules--5.4.205+gitAUTOINC+aaaf9f090d_943e7e1f32-r0-qemuarm-20220727082925.tgz
-rw-r--r-- 2 traskos traskos    242894 srp  3 12:23 core-image-minimal-qemuarm-20220803102311.testdata.json
lrwxrwxrwx 2 traskos traskos        55 srp  3 12:23 core-image-minimal-qemuarm.testdata.json -> core-image-minimal-qemuarm-20220803102311.testdata.json
lrwxrwxrwx 2 traskos traskos        57 srp  3 12:23 core-image-minimal-qemuarm.manifest -> core-image-minimal-qemuarm-20220803102311.rootfs.manifest
-rw-r--r-- 2 traskos traskos       948 srp  3 12:23 core-image-minimal-qemuarm-20220803102311.rootfs.manifest
lrwxrwxrwx 2 traskos traskos        55 srp  3 12:23 core-image-minimal-qemuarm.qemuboot.conf -> core-image-minimal-qemuarm-20220803102311.qemuboot.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 2 traskos traskos      1615 srp  3 12:23 core-image-minimal-qemuarm-20220803102311.qemuboot.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 2 traskos traskos   2265377 srp  3 12:23 core-image-minimal-qemuarm-20220803102311.rootfs.tar.bz2
lrwxrwxrwx 2 traskos traskos        56 srp  3 12:23 core-image-minimal-qemuarm.tar.bz2 -> core-image-minimal-qemuarm-20220803102311.rootfs.tar.bz2
lrwxrwxrwx 2 traskos traskos        53 srp  3 12:23 core-image-minimal-qemuarm.ext4 -> core-image-minimal-qemuarm-20220803102311.rootfs.ext4
-rw-r--r-- 2 traskos traskos   8388608 srp  3 12:26 core-image-minimal-qemuarm-20220803102311.rootfs.ext4
lrwxrwxrwx 2 traskos traskos        45 srp  3 14:05 test-img-qemuarm.testdata.json -> test-img-qemuarm-20220803120507.testdata.json
-rw-r--r-- 2 traskos traskos    238625 srp  3 14:05 test-img-qemuarm-20220803120507.testdata.json
lrwxrwxrwx 2 traskos traskos        47 srp  3 14:05 test-img-qemuarm.manifest -> test-img-qemuarm-20220803120507.rootfs.manifest
-rw-r--r-- 2 traskos traskos     19988 srp  3 14:05 test-img-qemuarm-20220803120507.rootfs.manifest
lrwxrwxrwx 2 traskos traskos        45 srp  3 14:05 test-img-qemuarm.qemuboot.conf -> test-img-qemuarm-20220803120507.qemuboot.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 2 traskos traskos      1575 srp  3 14:05 test-img-qemuarm-20220803120507.qemuboot.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 2 traskos traskos  31789813 srp  3 14:05 test-img-qemuarm-20220803120507.rootfs.tar.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 2 traskos traskos 179536896 srp  3 14:06 test-img-qemuarm-20220803120507.rootfs.ext4
lrwxrwxrwx 2 traskos traskos        43 srp  3 14:06 test-img-qemuarm.ext4 -> test-img-qemuarm-20220803120507.rootfs.ext4
lrwxrwxrwx 2 traskos traskos        46 srp  3 14:06 test-img-qemuarm.tar.bz2 -> test-img-qemuarm-20220803120507.rootfs.tar.bz2
```

Comment: please share us your test-img.bb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that when I deleted the tmp folder and created new clean build for the test-img, I could launch the image. I could launch **runqemu qemuarm**. This was caused because test-img was only one which could be launched.

The problem was caused by previous build of core-image-minimal inside deploy/images/qemuarm folder.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error it seems that your recipe is not correct. When you bake an image it should appear at build/tmp/deploy/images/

Here you have

```
 runqemu - ERROR - /home/traskos/yocto_live/build/tmp/deploy/images/test-img not a directory valid DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE
```

It would be easier to help if you provide your test-img.bb
Also, when you say "It is derived from core-image-minimal" did you mean you add in your test-img the following ?

```
inherit core-image
```

If not, you should try

Comment: I add the recipe into the question.

Comment: What I have to say, that when I add the "custom-recipe" package into the local.conf and rerun the core-image-minimal. And I run it through out QEMU it was working like it should.

Comment: I m not sure if this will work but add: 

export IMAGE_BASENAME = "test-img" inside your test-img.bb
I suspect that your test-img keep taking core-image-minimal as name.

Comment: into the test-image.bb recipe ?

Comment: Yes inside your recipe

Comment: please share the output of this command: ls -lrt /home/traskos/yocto_live/build/tmp/deploy/images/

Comment: total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 traskos traskos 4096 srp  3 14:06 qemuarm

Comment: Sadly the export command did not work.

Comment: Last hint, remove require recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb and add inherit core-image instead. then recompile. I m out of idea sorry

Comment: This will take some time.

Comment: Still same. Isn't it some type of runqemu where I can directly choose the img ?

Comment: Still I can not understand, why when i run runqemu core-image-minimal it will work without a problem.

Comment: inside your build/conf/local.conf check your MACHINE variable, what is it ?

Comment: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/qemu.html

Comment: I deleted the tmp folder and did the build again. This time it works. Maybe the problem was in building core-image-minimal beforehand and some "files", was not properly build again, when I build the test-img image. Could be this be the problem?

Comment: And if so is some way how to separete the image build, without new envinroment?